# Loading tables directly into list with lapply and custom function

Tags: r

I have a function that reads a specific file in a folder specified in lapply, and loads this table into R. The function looks like this:

```
load_files <- function(folder) {
  file <- list.files(path = paste0(folder, "/"), pattern = "quast.tsv")
  assign(
    paste0("ref_", gsub("^GCF_(.*?)_ASM(.*?)$", "\\1", folder)),
    read.delim(
      paste0(folder, "/", file),
      stringsAsFactors = F,
      header = TRUE,
      sep = "\t"
    )
  )
}
```

The function assigns a specific name to each data frame. Earlier I used this in a for-loop to create one data frame per table read. However, I want it to load each data frame into the same list, without loading them into individual data frames. The lapply I use look like this:

```
lapply(folder_names, load_files)
```

Where folder_names is basically just a character vector with the folder names identified with another function.

Is there any simple way to make the lapply load each assigned data frame directly into the same list?
I tried the following, but it didn't seem to work:

```
append(df_list, lapply(folder_names, load_files))
```

However this only returns the same as the lapply alone.

Comment: Why don't you read in the files in df_list and then use names(df_list) to name the loaded df's with a name based on your paste statement?

Comment: @phiver How would you go on and read in the files into df_list without doing the df_list <- list(df1, df2...)? The point is here that I only want the list in the global environment, not each separate data frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I would do. I have 2 text files in my working directory. And when done I have 2 data.frames in the list with their corresponding names.

```
file_list <- list.files( pattern = "*.txt")
file_list 
[1] "movies.txt" "mtcars.txt"

df_list <- lapply(file_list,
                  FUN = function(files) {
                    read.csv(files, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
                  })

str(df_list)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ X1..Jumanji..Adventure.Children.s.Fantasy: Factor w/ 2 levels "2::American President:The (1995)::Comedy|Drama|Romance",..: 1 2
 $ :'data.frame':   32 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ mpg.cyl.disp.hp.drat.wt.qsec.vs.am.gear.carb: Factor w/ 32 levels "AMC Javelin 15.2 8 304 150 3.15 3.435 17.3 0 0 3 2",..: 18 19 5 13 14 31 7 21 20 22 ...


files <- gsub(".txt", "", file_list)
files
[1] "movies" "mtcars"

names(df_list) <- files

str(df_list)
List of 2
 $ movies:'data.frame': 2 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ X1..Jumanji..Adventure.Children.s.Fantasy: Factor w/ 2 levels "2::American President:The (1995)::Comedy|Drama|Romance",..: 1 2
 $ mtcars:'data.frame': 32 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ mpg.cyl.disp.hp.drat.wt.qsec.vs.am.gear.carb: Factor w/ 32 levels "AMC Javelin 15.2 8 304 150 3.15 3.435 17.3 0 0 3 2",..: 18 19 5 13 14 31 7 21 20 22 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for seeing this from another perspective! Great answer

Comment: `df_list <- lapply(file_list, read.csv)` should be sufficient since all of the arguments you provided are the defaults. Also, if one or more are not, you could do `df_list <- lapply(file_list, read.csv, sep=";")` for example.